# Wordpress, same category structure, but different ID

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a really strange problem at the following page: 
http://iam.altervista.org/scritti/libri/

The list on the left bar calls the post of the same category.
Ex:  Liliana Bazzanella shows all the posts of Liliana Bazzanella.

I don't know why the name "Clara Bertolini Cestari" (and only that) doesn't works.

Actually every post is structured this way:
1 - Scritti (Father category of all posts of this page)
2 - Collane (Son category of "Scritti". Actually there are 3 sons: "libri", "collane" and "articoli"
3 - Name of the author (Son category of the category "Authors". There are a lot of authors about ten, but the sidebar shows them only if they have some post)

The problem is that if I make "var_dump" of a name of an author, it shows that the "name" of the category, inside the array, is at point 0:

```
$categories = get_the_category();<br />
$cat0 = $categories[0];<br />
```

If i var_dump "Clara Bertolini Cestari" the name of the category is not at point 0 but at point 1.

```
$categories = get_the_category();<br />
$cat0 = $categories\[1];
```

I tried to delete posts and category of "Clara Bertolini Cestari" and recreate them, but it always has the same problem.
If I create any new category or post with different name, keeps the same correct structure of the others, but with Clara...damn Clara!! XD

VAR_DUMP OF A POST

```
object(stdClass)#2321 (17) { ["term_id"]=> &int(14) 
["name"]=> &string(5)   "Libri" ["slug"]=> &string(5) "libri"  
["term_group"]=> int(0)   ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(14) ["taxonomy"]=> 
string(8) "category" ["description"]=> &string(0) "" ["parent"]=> &int(13) 
["count"]=> &int(7) ["object_id"]=> int(208) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"  
["cat_ID"]=> &int(14) ["category_count"]=> &int(7) 
["category_description"]=> &string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> &string(5) "Libri" 
["category_nicename"]=> &string(5) "libri" ["category_parent"]=> &int(13) }
```

VAR_DUMP OF A CLARA'S POST

```
object(stdClass)#2315 (17) { ["term_id"]=> &int(39) ["name"]=> &string(23) 
"Clara Bertolini Cestari" ["slug"]=> &string(23) "clara-bertolini-cestari" 
["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(39) ["taxonomy"]=> 
string(8) "category" ["description"]=> &string(0) "" ["parent"]=> &int(17) 
["count"]=> &int(1) ["object_id"]=> int(281) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
["cat_ID"]=> &int(39) ["category_count"]=> &int(1) 
["category_description"]=> &string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> &string(23) "Clara 
Bertolini Cestari" ["category_nicename"]=> &string(23) "clara-bertolini-
cestari" ["category_parent"]=> &int(17) }
```

The code used to fetch the data is this:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat0 = $categories[0];
$cat1 = $categories[1];


echo '<br />CAT=0<br />';
echo var_dump($cat0->name);
echo '<br />CAT=1<br />';
echo var_dump($cat1->name);
```

In a post page I should see something like this:
    CAT=0
    string(7) "Name son of "Scritti""
    CAT=1
    string(14) "Name son of "Authors"" 

For some reason in Clara's post it's inverted like this:
    CAT=0
    string(14) "Name son of "Authors"" 
    CAT=1
    string(7) "Name son of "Scritti""

Comment: Hint: var_dumps are much more readable if you preserve the line breaks and indendation.

Comment: <pre> with print_r is even better

Answer (score 0):

> 3 - Name of the author (Son category of the category "Authors". There are a lot of authors about ten, but the sidebar shows them only if they have some post)

Taken from your provided information.
You have to check your code, from your provided information it looks like you are hiding empty categories. That means only those categories are showing in the left bar of your page which posses any post.
For better understanding and for an exact solution can you provide your code which is being used to fetch categories, then it will be really easy to provide you exact solution. For better understanding about getting categories and relevant data visit [WordPress Codex Page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

Comment: Sorry I haven't explained the problem very well. Empty categories aren't shown because I've used jPlist and fortunately it's working correctly.
My problem is that category "Clara Bertolini Cestari" has the ID inverted. I mean every category has the son of "Scritti" category at $categories[0]; and the son of "Autori" at $categories[1];  while "Clara Bertolini Cestari" for unknown reasons has  the son of "Scritti" category at $categories[1]; and the son of "Autori" at $categories[0];   It inverts it's database

Comment: can you paste your code which is fetching categories data ? So, that I can provide you some thing more useful by checking that code ... hope that will work

Comment: This is the code that fetch the category of the post. It's working now on the site.

$categories = get_the_category();
$cat0 = $categories[0];
$cat1 = $categories[1];


echo '<br />CAT=0<br />';
echo var_dump($cat0->name);
echo '<br />CAT=1<br />';
echo var_dump($cat1->name);